# Post weird characters to a PHP script?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios4

I have an iPhone app where my data is posted to a PHP file on a server via GET. However, after executing with weird characters, there is no server response. (I put a NSLog on what I get returned from the server).

Here's how I post my data to the server:

```
// St uploading to server
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myflashpics.com/iphone_processes/upload.php?album=%@&id=%@&caption=%@&orient=%@&size=%d&device=iPhone",getAlbumID,theUserID,theCaption,getOrientation,imageSize];

        NSLog(@"Calling URL: %@", urlString);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: binary\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

And here's how I process server-side:

```
<?php

// Connect to MYSQL

$name = $_GET['name'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO *** (name) VALUES ('$name')");
```

I really would like to fix this server-side if all possible. I submitted to apple and I am hoping ti fix without resubmitting it.

Please please please help! Thanks

Coulton

Comment: I think you want $_POST rather than $_GET.

Comment: @Fosco: Posted one more line of code. Please look at it.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865049/weird-characters-in-php-get)? Why did you delete it?

Comment: @Coulton Vento, I still think the same.  Please put var_dump($_POST); and var_dump($_GET); in your PHP page so you can actually see what's getting submitted.

Comment: @alex: Yeah, I did... I'm sorry but I didn't get the response I was hoping and I had to reword it a bit.

Comment: @Coulton You know you can edit your posts, yeah? :)

Comment: @Fosco: `var_dump($_POST);` didn't return anything. But  `var_dump($_GET);` did.

Comment: @alex: yeah. I should of did that...

Comment: What should my content header be? Does it matter? Thanks.

Comment: @Coulton Vento, did it have the data you're looking for?

Comment: @Fosco: There is a server response with all the data when I don't include one of those characters. But if I do, there is no server response and the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using $_GET you should be url encoding your variables before sending them.

Anyways, you should be doing two things:

- escaping your request variables (GET or POST) with functions such as `mysql_escape_string` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before inserting it into the database
- encoding your variables for weird characters to numeric unicode characters (I beleive that is the correct term) using `mb_convert_encoding($variable, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` before storing them in the database

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

First off, if your action is creating a record, you should be doing a POST, not a GET.

Secondly, stop using the mysql_* functions and use PDO, with Parameterized queries.

If you're still having issues, use the php error_log() function in combination with var_export($var, true) to write out log messages to identify what PHP is retrieving.

That, combined with any errors/exceptions that are generated by PDO should give you an indication of where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I POST all the variables with my code I provided? Also, is there a way AT ALL I get get it working just with fixing it server-side? I submitted my app to apple and this is my second shot and I don't want to have to resubmit and wait another two weeks for them to even start reviewing it.

Comment: Here's a [PHP PDO tutorial](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3qMh8k_v2U8J:www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html+php+pdo&cd=3&hl=sv&ct=clnk&gl=se&source=www.google.se)\[Google Cache\]. See `->bindParam()`, the example is made with a `SELECT` statement, but works well with `INSERT` as well.

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me integrate my variables with my POST request (the first bit of code I provided). I decided I am going to do what's best and resubmit.